# Keep one instance of duplicate appearing in one of two columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, duplicates, uniqueidentifier

I've got a table containing one column with unique ID and one column with each unique ID's spouse ID (if they have a spouse). The problem is that each spouse ID also appears in the unique ID column, so when I pull a list, attempting to treat a couple as a single unit, I'm often doublecounting for a single couple.

What's a good, efficient way of taking a given list of unique IDs, checking to see if their spouse is also in the same list of unique IDs, and returning only one unique ID per couple?

The issue is a little more complicated in that sometimes both spouses are not included in the same list, so it's not simply a matter of keeping one person if they're married. In the event that the spouse isn't also in the same list, I want to make sure to retain the one that is. I also want to make sure I'm retaining all people who have a NULL value in the spouse ID column.

Subset of table in question:

```
Unique_ID      Spouse_ID
    1              2
    2              1
    3             NULL
    4             NULL
    5              10
    6              25
    7             NULL
    8              9
    9              8
   10              5
```

In this excerpt, ID's 3, 4, and 7 are all single. ID's 1, 2, 5, 8, and 9 have spouses that appear in the Unique_ID column. ID 6 has a spouse whose ID does not appear in the Unique_ID column. So, I'd want to keep ID's 1 (or 2), 3, 4, 5 (or 10), 6, 7, and 8 (or 9). Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

My inclination would be to combine the two lists and remove duplicates:

```
select distinct id
from ((select id
       from t
      ) union all
      (select spouse_id
       from t
       where spouse_id in (select id from t)
      )
     ) t
```

But, your question asked for an efficient way.  Another way to think about this is to add a new column which is the spouse id if in the id list or NULL otherwise (this uses a `left outer join`.  Then there are three cases:

1. There is no spouse id, so use the id
2. The id is less than the original id.  Use it.
3. The spouse id is less than the original id.  Discard this record, because the original is being used.

Here is an explicit way of expressing this:

```
select IdToUse
from (select t.*, tspouse.id tsid,
             (case when tspouse.id is null then t.id
                   when t.id < tspouse.id then t.id
                   else NULL
              end) as IdToUse
      from t left outer join
           t tspouse
           on t.spouse_id = tspouse.id
     ) t
where IdToUse is not null;
```

You can simplify this to:

```
  select t.*, tspouse.id tsid,
         (case when tspouse.id is null then t.id
               when t.id < tspouse.id then t.id
               else NULL
          end) as IdToUse
  from t left outer join
       t tspouse
       on t.spouse_id = tspouse.id
  where tspouse.id is null or
        t.id < tspouse.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Two tables is just plain bad design
Combine the tables

```
select id 
from table 
where id < spouseID
   or spouseID is null
```

Comment: This won't work, though, because sometimes the spouse isn't in the same list. By keeping only IDs that are less than their spouse's ID, I may lose a case that should have been included.

Comment: Two tables is just plain bad design.  Combine the tables.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. The data are not in two tables. The unique ID's and spouse ID's are two separate columns in the same table.

Comment: Then why do you state "not in same list".  Read my answer.  Two columns: one id two spouseID.  Post the table design.

Comment: I say "not in same list" because sometimes I'm taking a SUBSET of the data, where only one spouse meets the criteria for the pull. In that case, I'd want to keep all married people whose spouse does not appear in the list (i.e., treat them like a single person, since for all intens and purposes, they are "single" in my list). I'll post an excerpt of the table structure to give you an idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Show an example of where that query would miss a case that should have been included.

Comment: @Ian - Is it always the case that a pair, e.g. (1,2), will have the swapped pair, i.e. (2,1), in the table. If so, Blam's answer should work. The comparison eliminates the duplicates and the `NULL` check includes the singles/otherwise listed.